# how to redirect all subdomains to one file but let files that exist load

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so i have a domain.com, i want to make all subdomains to redirect to blog system im making

so domain.com - main website (not blog, loaded by index.php)
anything.domain.com - blog website -> everything redirected to blogs.php in main directory (same as index.php)

now to acomplish this i use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9_]+\.)domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) blogs.php [QSA,L]
```

and more or less it works (i use nice urls - get actual $_GET table extracted from $_SERVER[request_uri]

but, what i need on top of it is to be able to link files to existing directories like:
http://someblog.domain.com/js/somefile.js
now its trying to load blogs.php with /js/somefile.js as parameter

i tried to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

but with it - it always open main website (since every subdomain is redirected to main domain and act as existing dir/file)

so to sum up:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[*]+\.domain.com (xxx)! [NC] 
//in place of xxx - somehow check if there is anything after adderess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  // and check if it exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  //
```

if exists - server it, if not follow to old one that silently translates requests to blogs.php:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9_]+\.)gragieldowa.pl$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) blogs.php [QSA,L]
```

thanks in advance for any help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a pass-through at the beginning of your rules so anything that's `/index.php`, `/blogs.php`, or `/` gets passed through and no rewriting happens. Then you can do the domain/subdomain checks and the !-f and !-d checks.

```
# handle root request
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ blogs.php [L]

# redirect subdomains to blog.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blogs.php [L]
```

Comment: almost, 1) i dont need first rule - becouse that blogs.php is hidden from user, but tha i know how to fix myself:), but there is second problem - rule that should redirect to blogs.php doesnt work on xxx.domain.com (without anything after) becouse it redirects to website (index.php). To sum up - simple http://domain.com - > shouldnt be touch at all or redirected to index.php, but anything as subdomain (http://xxx.domain.com)- empty after or not existing dir/file - should be redirected to blogs.php. And one more thing - how do you insert new lines into reply here on stackoverflow x.x

Comment: @Krzysztof you can't insert newlines in a comment, you have to edit your question. I edited the rules so it ignores **domain.com** and adds a check for the root request `/`.

Comment: its still not working right:( let me sum up again: http://domain.com -> left alone or index.php (default behaviour), not existing file/dir http://domain.com/letssayxxx.php - > index.php, ANY subdomain: http://any.domain.com -> always to blogs.php, if file/dir exists from subdoimain http://any.domain.com/existingdir/existing.file - left alone, not existing, with subdomain address to blogs.php

Comment: and thanks for your time, i simply dont get those rules and how to make them work beside simple examples;/